# Failed to install ansible on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, software-installation, python, ansible

I cannot suceed to install ansible, I know the basic command is:

```
yum install ansible
```

but the output is:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install ansible Last metadata expiration check: 0:36:48 ago on Sun 13 Oct 2019 13:27:03 CEST. Error:   Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides PyYAML needed by ansible-2.8.5-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-setuptools needed by ansible-2.8.5-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-six needed by ansible-2.8.5-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-jinja2 needed by ansible-2.8.5-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python2-cryptography needed by ansible-2.8.5-1.el7.noarch 
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I already tryed the following commands:

> yum install -y epel-release yum install -y
>
> https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
>
> yum -y install python2
>
> yum install python3-pip
>
> pip3 install ansible

The output of `ansible --version` is:

> [root@localhost ~]# ansible --version
> ansible 2.8.5
> config file = None
> configured module search path =
> ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules',
> '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
> ansible python module location
> = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
> executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
> python version = 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:58:22) [GCC 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)]

Any help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: While the wrong one probably works (due to yum variables) you really ought to install the epel-release package intended for CentOS 8 instead of 7. https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

Comment: Like @jsbillings says, you need to use the right tool for the right job. Enabling epel-el7 wont deliver any packages to an el8 distribution. Also, like some answers say, you can easily install ansible via python3 and pip.

Answer (score 5):

It's well noted in one comment that `pip` should never bee run as `sudo` / under `root` user. Why is because it will very easily going to mess up RPM packaged Python packages with the ones installed by `pip`. Sooner or later something will stop working on this mess.

From [how to install Ansible in CentOS/RHEL 8](https://www.getpagespeed.com/work/install-latest-stable-ansible-on-centos-rhel-8), for CentOS 8 (in lack of subscription-based repository that RHEL 8 has), you can use `virtualenv` for a safe install:

```
sudo yum install python3 python3-virtualenv python3-pip

cd ~
mkdir ansible
virtualenv-3 ansible
. ansible/bin/activate
pip3 install ansible
```

Then you can directly invoke `~/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook` or add `~/ansible/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable to just run it with `ansible`.

Answer (score 1):

You should install python and pip:

```
sudo yum install python3 python3-pip
```

After this you'll are able to run:

```
sudo pip3 install ansible
```

Ansible successfully installed on CentOS 8

Comment: Thank you, the output is `WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.` Do you have a command to check is ansible was successfully installed ?

Comment: because `ansible --version` show `config file = None`

Comment: I would say: Don't install ansible at all. Use container wrapped ansible. https://hub.docker.com/search?q=ansible&type=image

Comment: might be preferable to install it with "--user" depending on usecase. Also, 'sudo pip install blah' is really, really, really unsafe. Really.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo yum install ansible
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

## How To Install Latest Ansible on EL8 distributions without EPEL, RPM/YUM/DNF, etc.

First, ensure python3 and python-installer are installed (using a root shell)...
(ok we ARE using Yum here, but only to make sure python3 and pip are installed.)

```
# yum install -y python3 python3-pip
```

and configured as the correct alternative for 'python'.

```
# alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
```

Now test that it is working. Do not use a root shell.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Now install ansible with python3-pip...

```
$ pip3 install ansible --user
```

Now test that ansible is also working.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.8.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/sheepdog/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jun 12 2019, 01:12:31) [GCC 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)]
```

Now, wasn't that easy?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today with yum installation command. CentOS comes with Python3 by default with version 8 of CentOS.

You can check it through `python3 -V`.

This should display the python version and if response is positive then move forward. Now we need to install `pip`:

```
sudo dnf install python3-pip
```

it will ask for confirmation twice. Select `y` every time.

Now we just need to install `ansible` here.

```
pip3 install ansible --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
yum install python2
yum install python39
yum install python3 python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip2 install ansible
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather install Ansible Core from AppStream, and use `ansible-galaxy collection install` to tailor your installation.

`yum install ansible-core`